# Почему класс Properties расширяет Hashtable<Object,Object>?

Tags: java

Будучи ещё только неработающим студентом, я не могу позволить себе думать, что разработчики стандартной библиотеки допускают столь заметные промахи, поэтому хочу уточнить, может в этом есть какой-то сакральный смысл?

В общем из-за того что, `Properties extends Hashtable<Object,Object>` мы ведь имеем кучу проблем, типа:

> Because Properties inherits from Hashtable, the put and putAll methods
>   can be applied to a Properties object. Their use is strongly
>   discouraged as they allow the caller to insert entries whose keys or
>   values are not Strings.

Почему нельзя было принять другое решение, типа `Properties extends Hashtable<String,String>`? Или вообще использовать композицию, чтобы не было возможности вызывать методы из класса `Hashtable`, а видны были только открытые методы самого класса `Properties`?

Comment: Кажется, это [работа для переводчиков](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873510/why-does-java-util-properties-implement-mapobject-object-and-not-mapstring-st). Вкратце, вы правы, это и правда промах :)

Comment: Если есть такой же вопрос с ответами на англоязычном ресурсе, следует ли мне удалить вопрос, или нет?

Comment: не стоит, мы предпочитаем переводы и ссылки.

Comment: Нет, удалять не надо, это же не дубликат, уже другой язык даёт существенное отличие. [Можно на Мете почитать соображения по этому поводу.](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2517/%D0%94%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ru-so/2534)

Comment: Если вам дали исчерпывающий ответ, то пометьте его как решение ("галочкой").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Обратите внимание, что в javadoc-е класса  `java.util.Properties` есть пометка `@since JDK1.0`. Т.е. класс существует со времен версии JDK 1.0.

Это обстоятельство влечет за собой пару последствий:

1. Поскольку это была первая версия API, то у разработчиков действительно был простор для неловких решений и косяков. Среди классов, появившихся до Java 5 можно найти немало таких примеров. Взять хотя бы `java.net.URL`.
2. До Java 5 не существовало обобщенных типов. То есть на самом деле `Properties` наследовал не `Hashtable<Object,Object>`, а просто `Hashtable`. После появления generic-ов `Hashtable` стал эквивалентен `Hashtable<Object,Object>`. И для поддержания краеугольного камня Java - обратной совместимости - нельзя было изменить контракт и начать использовать `Hashtable<String,String>`.